# Does inline ASM in C change disassembly?

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, inline-assembly, disassembly

I tried my best to search for this question before asking, but could not find an answer. Perhaps this question would be better suited to ask on the [Reverse Engineering SE](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/).

I am examining a 32-bit C Portable Executable that I suspect to make use of inline MSVC `__asm` inside of `main` as an anti-RE technique. Is there anything different about the disassembly of C programs using inline ASM that can help confirm my suspicions? Is it possible to discern from the disassembly if the original programmer used inline ASM?

This question mainly revolves around MSVC, but answers regarding GCC inline ASM may prove helpful to others.

Comment: What tool are you using for the examination of the executable?

Comment: "Is it possible...?" Not if the object code lacks annotation.

Comment: @SebDieBln I am using IDA and Ghidra.

Comment: There are several (typically legacy) instructions that a compiler would hardly ever use, so if you see those it is likely that inline assembly was used. Having said that, using inline asm does not in and of itself prevent reverse engineering in any meaningful way.

Comment: @JeffHolt: If you find an instruction (or sequence) that MSVC would never emit, for example obsolete instructions like `xlatb` or obsolete and slow instruction like `loop`, that would be pretty clear evidence.  (If you knew the details of old MSVC versions well enough to know that some old compiler version didn't do that.)  Or finding a jump into the middle of another instruction would be another good sign of obfuscation.  But it might be a later obfuscator, rather than manual inline asm.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Agreed. However, the disassembly includes something like
`push 3` 
`pop  gs` 
`mov  ax, gs` 
`cmp  al, 3` 
I'm fairly sure this is an anti-debugging technique.

Comment: If it is, I don't understand how it would work, which is of course entirely possible. I actually can't remember what, if anything, `gs:` is used for in 32-bit mode, or whether you're allowed to modify it.